# Does isomorphic groups have the same Hasse diagram?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I know that if we have $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n $ , and $m,n$ are prime beetween them, then we have $\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n \approxeq \mathbb{Z}_{mn}$. But does that also mean that the Hasse diagram will be exactly the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the Hasse diagram of subgroups and their inclusions then yes, that information is invariant under isomorphism.

If $\phi\colon G \to G'$ is an isomorphism and $H \subseteq K \subseteq G$ are subgroups then $\phi(H) \subseteq \phi(K)$ are subgroups of $G'$.